# push notification not coming in iOS 9 using parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, ios9

I am creating an iOS application using parse.Previously I was able to get push notification but after upgrading from iOS8 to iOS9 it's not coming.I am really stuck.I have followed each and every steps provided by Apple and Parse .Please help me or provide me a solution so that I can move forward.

Anyways thanks in advance.

Comment: Without giving ***any*** information whatsoever about what the current situation is and what you have tried, how are we supposed to help you? Have you tried ... yet?

Comment: Delete the PFInstallation for your device, log in to parse again and try.

Comment: Hi it's working Previously I used to send the pushType in PFInstallation .After commenting that part it's working fine>i just got to know:
They have a guide on how to update the deviceToken for an Installation object.
pushType: This field is reserved for directing Parse to the push delivery network to be used for Android devices. This parameter is not supported in iOS/OS X devices (readonly).